# Call names of a vector or list

Tags: r, get

I have a vector named "vec". I label the elements from "a" to "m"

```
vec <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4)
names(vec) <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m")
```

Then I split the vec according to the sequences.

```
split_vec <- split(vec, vec)
```

Now when I type
`Spec_vec$"1"` I get the first list.

Instead of typing the specific name as "1". I want to get the values 
such as

`spec_vec$vec[1]`
But the above function doesn't work. Is there a way to get that?

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
split_vec[[as.character(vec[1])]]
# a b c 
# 1 1 1
```

Notice that you need `as.character`, since just the number value from `vec[i]` would give incorrect results for calls like `split_vec[[vec[10]]]` where you would expect the third element.

```
split_vec[[vec[10]]]
# Error in split_vec[[vec[10]]] : subscript out of bounds

split_vec[[as.character(vec[10])]]
# j k l m 
# 4 4 4 4
```

But in general, it's best to avoid such names that begin with numerics because, obviously, it's quite awkward and can cause trouble.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. This is exactly what I am looking for